# Break the HTML file into fixed size pages

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I would like to display the content of a HTML file,in the form of book with many pages(not side by side pages, but one after the other, like PDF), when opened in some browser. Say, i define page width=600px and height=800pz, the content should fit into one page and the remaining should overflow to next page and like that. And it should work for any HTML file. 
How can i break the content into pages ? In any way XSL helps me to achieve it ?

Comment: You can do this with a pagination plugin like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination

Comment: @Grillz I think that is not what he means. He wants to do this for arbitrary HTML content

Comment: I guess not. I am still not 100% clear on what he is looking for actually.

Comment: @Grillz, Example, in Adobe epub reader, they display HTML contents in page wise. In ipad, they display HTML(epub books) page by page. They are breaking a continuous content into pages, right ? i want the same functionality...

Comment: yes, but those are *applications*. They have their own HTML renderer. They can do whatever they want with the content. Javascript cannot.

Comment: @Gpathy Nicely asked, giving up, Now I want to implement this in iPhone/iPad app using HTML file. Could you please post your answer.. I want to display one after another in my iPhone.. it's not a big problem but how can i Split into more pages.

Answer (score 0):

This should be theoretically possible by putting the document into an `iframe` that is 800 pixels high, and changing the scroll position inside that iframe (Page 1 = 0px; Page 2 = 800px; Page 3 = 1600px ....)

The HTML page in question would have to be on your domain, though.

There is no proper way to actually display those pages side by side, though. You'd have to clone the whole document for as many times as there are pages, and display as many `iframe` s with the page scrolled to different positions.

Depending on what  you want to do, it might be better to use a different technology for this (e.g.  having a browser print out a web page to a PDF file, splitting the content into pages in the process.)

Comment: Well, i dont want to display side by side. One after the other ( downwards, life PDF) is fine. But i dont want to convert into PDF. I just need a technique for making the line which can not fit completely into current page, should overflow to next page. can I use iframe for that ?

Comment: @Gpathy you just want to insert a line? That should be possible using jQuery and an iframe, but the page would have to be on your domain

Comment: "insert line" ? i wont be inserting any line. I wont be changing the contents, instead i just break them into pages. So that user can number them into pages (like PDF)

Comment: @Gpathy sorry, I misread your first comment. Side by side display is impossible except by the horrendous method I describe (cloning the documents). I'm fairly sure there is no way to do this other than that way.

Comment: Pekka, sorry, are you saying "there is no way to do this other than that way" this for side by side display or one after the other downwards( life PDF) display ? I want later one...                                                                Scrolling to different positions (0px, 800px, 1600px) is not sophisticated way. Currently i am doing like that only. But the problem is, as there is no overflow, lines cut in the middle. i.e in most of the time,half of the line will be visible at the end of the pages,

Comment: @Gpathy I'm fairly sure there is no way to do this in a good way using HTML, CSS and Javascript. What is your goal with this?

Comment: @Gpathy So you're saying if a sentence can't fit at the end of a page, you want the entire sentence to instead shift to the next page?

Comment: @Pekka, Nate Bundy, Example, in Adobe epub reader, they display HTML contents in page wise. In ipad, they display HTML(epub books) page by page. They are breaking a continuous content into pages, right ? i want the same functionality...

Answer (score 0):

If you want PDF style functionality, convert the html on the fly into a pdf and then embed it in the page. You can specify the width and other params when you are generating the pdf.