# Is there a way to break HTML content into "pages" of fixed height?

Tags: html, css

In a word processor or desk-top publishing software, the page containers are of a fixed size and the text as it is input sort of flows through those containers regardless of how its various pieces are formatted/styled.  Is there anyway to do something similar in HTML whether through using JS or server-side code to build it?

I don't want to accept input from the user and have a dynamic flow of content; but would like to be able to hold the HTML of my documents in a database and then break them into the fixed "page" containers such that the HTML will match a downloadable PDF in terms of page layout.  I can do it manually for a specific document but wondered if there was some better way.

The only [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584790/break-the-html-file-into-fixed-size-pages) I came across here is 11 years old.

I thought perhaps that if there is not a reasonable method of creating containers for this, absolute-position horizontal lines could be used to annotate where the page breaks are.  There just wouldn't be any page separation in form of visible spacing.  If the user was able to vary the font-size, the location of the horizontal lines would need to be able to be recalculated.

Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: I doubt that it is possible, anyway - why don't you want to display html page to user and let user's browser to split it into pages during printing? thus you will accomodate any paper sizes used by user, so it is much more flexible and long term solution

Comment: btw, you can try https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp attribute, but it does not guarantee height

Comment: @IłyaBursov Thank you.  It's not for printing but for searching.  I'd like to make it possible for the reader to search the html and get the page number for citation reference.

Comment: then I suggest to use internal links https://way2tutorial.com/html/html_internal_links.php#:~:text=HTML%20Links%20%2D%20HTML%20Internal%20Link&text=HTML%20internal%20link%20is%20linked,link%20to%20the%20same%20page.